# Обновить данные родительского окна из дочернего окна. C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть родительское окно, в нем объявлена страница, на странице находится кнопка(Редактирования). По нажатию на кнопку откроется окно, после его закрытия данные в родительском окне должны обновится.

**Вьюха Родительского окна**

```
public class MasterWinViewModel : Notify
{
    private object _curentPage;

    public object CurentPage
    {
        get { return _curentPage; }
        set
        {
            _curentPage = value;
            SignalChanged("CurentPage");
        }
    }

    public UserApi ProfileUser
    { 
        get => profileUser;
        set 
        {
            profileUser = value;
            SignalChanged("ProfileUser");
        } 
    }
    public CustomCommand Main { get; set; }
    public CustomCommand Help { get; set; }
    public CustomCommand Search { get; set; }
    public CustomCommand MyMediaLibrary { get; set; }
    public CustomCommand Profile { get; set; }
    public CustomCommand Test { get; set; }

    private UserApi profileUser;

    public MasterWinViewModel()
    {

        Task.Run(GetUserId);

       


        Test = new CustomCommand(() =>
        {
            Test nn = new Test();
            nn.Show();
        });

        Main = new CustomCommand(() =>
        {
            CurentPage = new MainPage();
            SignalChanged("CurentPage");
        });

        Help = new CustomCommand(() =>
        {
            CurentPage = new HelpPage();
            SignalChanged("CurentPage");
        });

        Search = new CustomCommand(() =>
        {
            CurentPage = new SearchPage();
            SignalChanged("CurentPage");
        });

        MyMediaLibrary = new CustomCommand(() =>
        {
            CurentPage = new MyMediaLibraryPage();
            SignalChanged("CurentPage");
        });

        Profile = new CustomCommand(() =>
        {
            CurentPage = new ProfilePage();
            SignalChanged("CurentPage");
        });
    }

    public async Task GetUserId()
    {
        Task.Delay(200).Wait();
        var t = SingInWindowViewModel.UsId;
        var result = await Api.GetAsync<UserApi>(t, "User");
        ProfileUser = result;
        SignalChanged("ProfileUser");
    }
   
    

}
```

**Въюха страницы**

```
public class ProfilePageViewModel : Notify
{
    private CustomCommand selectedAlbum;
    private List<AlbumApi> albums;

    public CustomCommand SelectedAlbum
    {
        get => selectedAlbum;
        set
        {
            selectedAlbum = value;
            SignalChanged();
        }
    }

    public List<AlbumApi> Albums 
    {
        get => albums;
        set 
        {
            albums = value;
            SignalChanged("Albums");
        } 
    }

    public CustomCommand NewAlbum { get; set; }
    public UserApi ProfileUser { get; set; }
    public CustomCommand Edit { get; set; }
    public CustomCommand EditAlbum { get; set; }
    public CustomCommand DeleteAlbum { get; set; }
    public CustomCommand Refresh { get; set; }


    public ProfilePageViewModel()
    {
        Task.Run(GetUserId);
        Task.Run(GetAlbumsList);

        Refresh = new CustomCommand(() =>
        {
            Task.Run(GetUserId);
            Task.Run(GetAlbumsList);
        });


        Edit = new CustomCommand(() =>
        {
            EditUserWindow euw = new EditUserWindow();
            euw.ShowDialog();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Task.Run(GetUserId);
            
        });

        NewAlbum = new CustomCommand(() =>
        {
            AddAlbumWindow albumWindow = new AddAlbumWindow();
            albumWindow.Show();
        });
    }


    public async Task GetUserId()
    {
        var t = SingInWindowViewModel.UsId;
        var result = await Api.GetAsync<UserApi>(t, "User");
        ProfileUser = result;
        SignalChanged("ProfileUser");
    }

    public async Task GetAlbumsList()
    {
        var result = await Api.GetListAsync<AlbumApi[]>("Album");
        Albums = new List<AlbumApi>(result);
        SignalChanged("Albums");
    }


    public void Load()
    {
        Task.Run(GetUserId);
        Task.Run(GetAlbumsList);
    }
}
```

**Въюха окна редактирования**

```
public class EditUserWindowViewModel : Notify
{
    private BitmapImage image;
    public BitmapImage Image 
    { 
        get => image;
        set 
        {
            image = value;
            SignalChanged("Image");
        } 
    }

    public UserApi EditUser { get; set; }
    public CustomCommand SelectImage { get; set; }
    public CustomCommand SaveUser { get; set; }

    public EditUserWindowViewModel()
    {
        Task.Run(GetUserId);

        SaveUser = new CustomCommand(() =>
        {
            Task.Run(EditUsers);
            foreach (Window window in Application.Current.Windows)
            {
                if (window.DataContext == this)
                {
                    
                    CloseWin(window);
                }
            }
            
        });

        string directory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
        SelectImage = new CustomCommand(() =>
        {
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                try
                {
                    var info = new FileInfo(ofd.FileName);
                    Image = GetImageFromPath(ofd.FileName);
                    EditUser.Image = $"/Resource/{info.Name}";
                    var newPath = directory.Substring(0, directory.Length) + EditUser.Image;
                    if (!File.Exists(newPath))
                        File.Copy(ofd.FileName, newPath, true);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Код ошибки: Image Error", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void CloseWin(object obj)
    {
        Window win = obj as Window;
        win.Close();
    }

    private BitmapImage GetImageFromPath(string url)
    {
        BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
        img.BeginInit();
        img.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        img.UriSource = new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute);
        img.EndInit();
        return img;
    }

    public async Task EditUsers()
    {
        await Api.PutAsync<UserApi>(EditUser, "User");
    }

    public async Task GetUserId()
    {
        var t = SingInWindowViewModel.UsId;
        var result = await Api.GetAsync<UserApi>(t, "User");
        EditUser = result;
        SignalChanged("EditUser");
    }

    
    
}
```

Comment: Передаете в дочернее экземпляр того что оно должно заполнить, при закрытии проверяете результат. То есть ссылка у главного окна должна быть на данные изначально, еще до открытия дочернего.

Comment: Правильно ли я понял? Я должен в объявлении экземпляра дочернего окна в аргумент передать что он должен заполнить те или иные элементы ? Второе предложение не совсем понял. Если есть возможность примера кода , был бы благодарен

Comment: `var instance = new MyData(); new MyWindow(instance).ShowDialog(); ...`